# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-16000: database open for read-only access

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have an spring batch application which reads data from Database and writes the result in a .dat file.
The job runs fine in the DB having read and write permissions.But if I run the job with the DB having only read access. I'm getting the below error...

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Could not obtain sequence value;nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-16000: 
database open for read-only access
```

My Query is a simple select statement.Don't know what is the root cause for this error.Please suggest

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the query in question?

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: Your connection or session is read-only, or the database instance is read-only? That seems to be what the error is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You did not posted your query so I will just assume, that you are trying to select from a non-local table via DB_LINK and Oracle starts a transaction, just in case.

Try to set your transaction read-only too, before executing your query:

```
set transaction read only;
```